# Do double integrals always give a volume?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to figure out more concretely what double integrals give.

Say:
$$\iint f(x,y) \ dA $$

Essentially, what is happening, is the integration of a function over an area? 
If we break it down integral by integral. 
What do you get after a first integration by $dx$ or $dy$? 
Should I consider all double integrals as volumes, with some having a $z = 1$ so, no volume?

Comment: If $f$ is height the double integral is volume. But if $f$ is pressure the double integral is force. Or if $f$ is intensity (in, say $Wm^{-2}$) the double integral is power (in $W$). Lots of others - it depends on what is easiest in your context.

Comment: Does that mean that triple integrals can represent the volume of a 4D object?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky: Yes, a triple integral over the domain $V=[a_1,b_1]\times [a_2,b_2]\times[a_3,b_3]$ is the "hypervolume" under the graph of a function $f:V\to\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The topic of **double integrals**

$$\iint_D f(x,y) \ dxdy$$

affirms that from the geometric point of view it can be interpreted as the volume of the solid obtained by extending the plane region $D$ until the graph of the function $z=f(x,y)$.

The term $f(x,y) \ dxdy$
represents, in fact, the volume of the infinitesimal parallelepiped having base area and height given by $z=f(x,y)$. With the double integral, the volumes of the infinite infinitesimal parallelepipeds are then added together.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

If you think of an ordinary integral $ \int _ a ^ b g ( x ) \, \mathrm d x $ as an area (or a signed area in case $ g $ might take negative values), then you can think of a double integral $ \int _ R f ( x , y ) \, \mathrm d A $ as a volume (or a signed volume in case $ f $ might take negative values).  If you have an iterated integral $ \int _ a ^ b \int _ { g ( x ) } ^ { h ( x ) } f ( x , y ) \, \mathrm d y \, \mathrm d x $, then the inner integral calculates an area for each value of $ x $, and these areas together make up the volume.

But area is not the *only* way to think of an integral.  Going back to the iterated integral $ \int _ a ^ b \int _ { g ( x ) } ^ { h ( x ) } f ( x , y ) \, \mathrm d y \, \mathrm d x $, if you want to think of the *outer* integral as an area, then this is a different geometric metaphor than the one which sees the *inner* integrals as areas and the double integral as a volume.  (Basically, once you calculate $ \int _ { g ( x ) } ^ { h ( x ) } f ( x , y ) \, \mathrm d y $ as an area for each value of $ x $, you then reinterpret this area as a length before doing the outer integral as an area.)  You could actually take *any* integral $ \int _ a ^ b g ( x ) \, \mathrm d x $ and think of it as a volume, if you think of the values of $ g $ as areas instead of lengths.  It's just that usually there's no need to make it more geometrically complicated like that.

In the other direction, if you're integrating a constant function (especially one with the value $ 1 $), then it's natural to interpret everything one dimension lower.  So $ \int _ a ^ b 1 \, \mathrm d x $ is the area of a rectangle with length $ b - a $ and height $ 1 $, but it's also just the length $ b - a $.  Similarly, $ \int _ R 1 \, \mathrm d A $ is the volume of a prism whose base is $ R $ and whose height is $ 1 $, but it's also just the area of $ R $.

Another way that $ \int _ a ^ b f ( x ) \, \mathrm d x $ could be a length, or more precisely a distance, is if $ x $ represents time and $ f ( x ) $ represents speed.  There's no direct analogue of this for double integrals, since we don't have two dimensions of time.  But hopefully this highlights how thinking of integrals as areas, volumes, etc is just one of many applications of the concept.